# QGIS and intersections

Tags: qgis, intersection, query

I have MultiLineString geometry data from an ESRI shapefile.  I also have a polygon (region) that I have created in QGIS using the drawing tools.

When I attempt to find the intersection between the two features using the Geoprocessing tools I end up with an empty set.

If I use the Spatial Query plugin, the features I want are correctly identified but when I try to create a layer I receive the following error: "The query from "YourLayer" using "FID" is not possible".

Comment: If the FID is not unique, you can't draw a layer in QGIS

Comment: Try to set another field from your table to intersect instead of "FID"

Comment: Could you perhaps share your shapefiles on a public server so that others could test it?

Comment: It will still have to be unique; the issue here is it will not display unless it has a uid.

I guess you didn't like me putting it that way....

Comment: Are both shapefile in the same CRS? This migth originate empty results.